# Can receive ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED via manifest but not programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, manifest

Why is it that I can register a broadcast receiver for "android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" via the manifest file but not programmatically using the following:

```
    IntentFilter iFilter = new IntentFilter();
    iFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED");
    registerReceiver(powerStateListener, iFilter);
```

What is the best way to determine which intents must be registered for via the manifest and which can be done programmatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the documentation is a little obtuse here.
It's actually only documented on [ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED):

> You can not receive this through components declared in manifests,
>   only by explicitly registering for it with Context.registerReceiver().
>   See ACTION_BATTERY_LOW, ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY, ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED,
>   and ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED for distinct battery-related broadcasts
>   that are sent and **can be received through manifest receivers**

So, as I understand the documentation, ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED can only be received by a registered receiver, and ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED can only be received by a receiver named in the manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  So is the "trial and error" approach the only way to determine this for all intents?